# Deploying a Rest webservice on JBoss gives error [STDRR]....How it can be removed from JBoss logs & what kind of error it is?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Actually I am using the jersey framework for developing Rest web service so while deploying the rest webservice on JBoss...it gives ERROR (STDERR) in JBoss logs.see this log--

ERROR [STDERR] 17-Jul-2014 06:02:32 com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages: com.ba.ce.me.rest 06:02:32,845 ERROR [STDERR] 17-Jul-2014 06:02:32 com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses INFO: Root resource classes found: class com.ba.ce.me.rest.De 06:02:32,846 ERROR [STDERR] 17-Jul-2014 06:02:32 com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init

Comment: Please, provide more information on the error, provably the complete stack trace, or some of the code.

Comment: Actually, add the details to the question's body so it becomes better and so attract more people to answer it.

Comment: #Alfergon...details are added..thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, it's logging at INFO level. You need to configure the logging system of Jersey to either log to an approved location (and not STDERR) or to log actual errors.

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thanks @Tassos...I am new to jersey framework...could u elaborate how to configure the logging system or any other solution for this ?

Comment: Jersey uses JDK logging; configure that and you're set. See the [logging overview javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html) for a starting point.